# Why stop Pollard's rho after $\sqrt{N}$ iterations and not $\sqrt[4]{N}$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $N = pq$ where $p < q$, both prime.  It is believed that Pollard's rho expects $\sqrt{p}$ steps on average.  It's a fact that $p \leq \sqrt{N}$, so $\sqrt{p} \leq \sqrt[4]{N}$.  This means it is believed that the algorithm should stop around $\sqrt[4]{N}$ steps.  But look at this [Racket implementation](https://github.com/racket/math/blob/master/math-lib/math/private/number-theory/number-theory.rkt#L352).  They're running the loop up to $\sqrt{N}$.

```
;;; ALGORITHM 19.8  Pollard's rho method
; INPUT   n>=3 neither a prime nor a perfect power
; OUTPUT  Either a proper divisor of n or #f
(: pollard : Natural -> (U Natural False))
(define (pollard n)
  (let ([x0 (random-natural n)])
    (do ([xi x0 (remainder (+ (* xi xi) 1) n)]
         [yi x0 (remainder (+ (sqr (+ (* yi yi) 1)) 1) n)]
         [i  0  (add1 i)]
         [g  1  (gcd (- xi yi) n)])
      [(or (< 1 g n) (> i (sqrt n)))
       (if (< 1 g n)
           (cast g natural?)
           #f)])))
```

Question.  Shouldn't they run it up to $\sqrt[4]{N}$ and not $\sqrt{N}$?  What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like they just run the worst case scenario (if we forget the failure possibility even in that case). Running the _expected_ number of iterations is not too wise either.

Comment: It's $O(\root4\of N)$ rather than exactly $\root4\of N$, so you want a bit of elbow room. But, you are right (+1). It feels a bit strange to go up to $\sqrt{N}$, because you are guaranteed to find the smallest prime factor (if one exists) by trivial division in $O(\sqrt N)$ tests.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Yes, some elbow room seems to make sense, but going up to $\sqrt{N}$ seems too much.  But how much elbow room should we have?  Any ideas?